# java, component only shows up when added directly to frame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

I've made a simple dice game, I have a DiceFace Class which defines a diceFace

```
    package panel;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.geom.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class DiceFace
     {

  // Holds the seven possible dot positions on a standard die
  private Ellipse2D.Double[] dots = new Ellipse2D.Double[7];

 private Rectangle box;
 private int xLeft;
 private int yTop;
 private int side;
 private int diceValue;

public DiceFace(int s, int x, int y, int v)
{
    side = s;       // dimension of dice face
    xLeft = x;      // position
    yTop = y;       // position
    diceValue = v; // pip value
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2)
{
    box = new Rectangle(xLeft, yTop, side, side);
  makeDots();

  // Black background
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g2.fill(box);
  // White dots on black
  g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    // Draw dots
  if (diceValue == 1) 
        g2.fill(dots[0]);
  else if (diceValue == 2)
  {
     g2.fill(dots[1]); g2.fill(dots[2]);
  }
  else if (diceValue == 3)
  {
     g2.fill(dots[0]); g2.fill(dots[1]); g2.fill(dots[2]);
  }
  else if (diceValue == 4)
  {
     g2.fill(dots[1]); g2.fill(dots[2]);
     g2.fill(dots[3]); g2.fill(dots[4]);
  }
  else if (diceValue == 5)
  {
     g2.fill(dots[0]); g2.fill(dots[1]);
     g2.fill(dots[2]); g2.fill(dots[3]); g2.fill(dots[4]);
   }
  else if (diceValue == 6)
  {
     g2.fill(dots[1]); g2.fill(dots[2]); g2.fill(dots[3]);
     g2.fill(dots[4]); g2.fill(dots[5]); g2.fill(dots[6]);
   }
}


public void makeDots()
{
   int w = side/6;   // dot width
   int h = side/6;   // dot height

   dots[0] =  new Ellipse2D.Double(xLeft + (2.5 * side)/6,
                                     yTop + (2.5 * side)/6, h, w);

   dots[1] = new Ellipse2D.Double(xLeft + (3.75 * side)/6,
                                    yTop + (3.75 * side)/6, h, w);

   dots[2] = new Ellipse2D.Double(xLeft + (1.25 * side)/6,
                                    yTop + (1.25 * side)/6, h, w);

   dots[3] = new Ellipse2D.Double(xLeft + (1.25 * side)/6,
                                    yTop + (3.75 * side)/6, h, w);

   dots[4] = new Ellipse2D.Double(xLeft + (3.75 * side)/6,
                                    yTop + (1.25 * side)/6, h, w);

   dots[5] =  new Ellipse2D.Double(xLeft + (1.25 * side)/6,
                                     yTop + (2.5 * side)/6, h, w);

   dots[6] =  new Ellipse2D.Double(xLeft + (3.75 * side)/6,
                                     yTop + (2.5 * side)/6, h, w);
}
```

}

I also have a class DiceFaceConstructor which extends JComponent

```
package panel;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;


public class DiceFaceComponent extends JComponent {



public void paintComponent(Graphics g) //method returns void, takes object of type           Graphics which it refers to internally as g
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g; //casting 

    DiceFace dice1 = new DiceFace(60,0,0,6);  
    dice1.draw(g2); //draw the andgate  
    }
```

}

finally I have a viewer class which has a main method and a frame. Drawing a new dice face object directly on the frame works just fine (dice is displayed), as below 
        package panel;

```
    import java.awt.Component;

    import javax.swing.JComponent;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class PanelViewer
    {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{

 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setSize(600, 400);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.add(dice1)
 DiceFaceComponent dice1 = new DiceFaceComponent();
     frame.add(dice1)
 //JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
 //panel1.add(dice1);

 //frame.add(panel1);
 //frame.pack();
 frame.setVisible(true); 




}

      }
```

The problem is when I try adding my dice component to a panel and then adding the panel to the frame nothing is shown, as below. Please help, its been five hours.

```
    package panel;

    import java.awt.Component;

    import javax.swing.JComponent;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class PanelViewer
     {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{

 JFrame frame = new JFrame();
 frame.setSize(600, 400);
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 DiceFaceComponent dice1 = new DiceFaceComponent();
 JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
 panel1.add(dice1);
 frame.add(panel1);
 frame.pack();
 frame.setVisible(true); 




}

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a layout problem. A JFrame uses BorderLayout by default and a JPanel uses FlowLayout. By adding the DiceFaceComponent JComponent to the FlowLayout-using JPanel, the DiceFaceComponent JComponent will try to size to its preferredSize which is likely [0, 0] or at most [1, 1]. One quick solution is to give the JPanel BorderLayout, and then your JComponent would fill it and show.

Another option is to

- Give your DiceFace class a `public Dimension getPreferredSize()` that returns a Dimension that is big enough to show the image. This will not be a method override.
- give the DiceFaceComponent JComponent a private DiceFace field, one that can be set by its constructor and possibly changed (if desired) with a setter method.
- Have the DiceFaceComponent JComponent paintComponent method override draw this DiceFace instance if it's not null. Don't have it create a new DiceFace instance within the method.
- give the DiceFaceComponent JComponent a `getPreferredSize()` override method that helps it to intelligently choose its best size. Your method will check if the DiceFace instance is null and if it is, call the super method, other wise it will call the DiceFace instance's `getPreferredSize()` method.